# When may function (meromorphic) be expanded as power series with coefficients of integers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, computability-theory, formal-languages, meromorphic-functions

Let $F$ be meromorphic function, with what properties may it be expanded as power series with coefficients of integers in such a form:

$$F=\sum_0^{\infty}a_i x^i,a_i\in \mathbb{N} \bigcup 0,\exists M \space a_i \leq M^i$$.

and when the coefficients consist of  a sequence  of computably enumerable relation.

If the question is ambiguous, please tell me.

When may function (meromorphic) be expanded as power series with coefficients of integers

Comment: Without specifying what kind of properties you are asking for, this seems too open-ended for me. How about "F has the property that it may be expanded as a power series with integer coefficients"? Perfectly well-defined property.

Comment: I assume you mean on the whole complex plane. The power series coefficients come from C, so there are very few meromorphic functions with integer coefficients. Certainly 1/z^k * f(z) for f(z) = e(z), sin(z), cos(z), but it's hard to say something specific. Can you expound on your question?

Comment: @Robert,sorry, I mean on disk of complex plane

Comment: @Robert: A power series with integer coefficients can never converge on the whole complex plane, unless it is a polynomial. Indeed, the Cauchy–Hadamard theorem implies that a series with integer coefficients, infinitely many of which are nonzero, has radius of convergence at most $1$.

Comment: A sufficient condition is: Write the meromorphic function as quotient $f/g$ of homolomorphic functions. If the powerseries of $f$ and $g$ (around the origin) have integral coefficients and $g(0) = 1$ holds, than the powerseries of the meromorphic function will also have integral coefficients. 

Comment: @Robert: Can you please clarify what $1/z^k*f(z) ...$ means.For instance, $z^{-1}\cdot sin(z)$ doesn't epand with integral coefficients.

Comment: It's easy to find examples that are rational functions (generating functions of linear recursive sequences), or have branch points (e.g. $\sqrt{1+4z}$) or a natural boundary (lacunary functions).  Is there an example that is meromorphic on $\mathbb C$ but not a rational function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was a large research subject in 1930-s. The key authors are G. Polya, Ch. Pisot
and Raphael Robinson.
The book of Bieberbach, Analytische Fortsetzung (in German, there is a Russian translation) contains a chapter with a survey
of these results.

The general spirit of these results is the following: if you have a Taylor series
with integer coefficients which has an analytic or meromorphic continuation
in sufficiently large region, then the function must be rational, and in certain
cases all such functions can be explicitly described.
But there are too many results to mention them here.

By the way, the question is equivalent, via Borel-Laplace transform to a question about
entire functions which take integer values at positive integers.
So "Integer-values entire functions" is just another name of the same topic.

Comment: @Alexandre Thank you,but I don't know German nor do I know Russian.The results are so interesting.

Comment: Pisot's papers are in French and Robinson in English.

Comment: @Alexandre，Thank you ,I highly appreciate your answer

Comment: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1968-130-03/S0002-9947-1968-0219706-9/S0002-9947-1968-0219706-9.pdf